# My laptop microphone is auto muting and unmuting all the time

Tags: linux, arch-linux, microphone, pulse-audio

Suddenly my laptop microphone is auto muting and unmuting. I don't have any clue what's the problem. I'm using Arch Linux with KDE. This is so annoying to see microphone muted notification in the middle of the screen all the time.

Comment: By any chance could Fn lock be on? Does all keys work without ill effects?

Comment: I think this is a keyboard issue after disabling extra keys the problem was solved.